# NCFTPPUT command problem

Tags: ftp

I using passive mode FTP command provide by NCFTP, Currently i want to pass a raw ftp command after file transferred. i found that got an option to do that:

ncftpput -u user -p password -X "rename 123.exe 1234.exe" host /path C:\123.exe

however, it is not working. It can put the file, but rename command not working.

Have anyone did that before?Pls help

Answer (score 3):

> -X use RAW FTP commands

Use the following syntax:

```
ncftpput -u user -p password -X "RNFR 123.exe" -X "RNTO 1234.exe" host /path/123.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with ncftls as well. It is more immediate if you what you have to do is just a rename without actually uploading anything on the FTP server. 
(-W is like -X. The only difference is that it does the rename immediately after logging in)
Here is the syntax:

ncftpls -u name -p psw  -W "RNFR FTPfolder/anotherFolder/OLDname.txt" -W "RNTO FTPfolder/anotherFolder/NEWname.txt" ftp://ftp.name.org